# AdMob banner loaded but not display on device in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

My code to develop is following in xml file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

and in java file

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);        
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            showMessage("banner loaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            showMessage("error banner : "+ errorCode);
        }
    });
```

in manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.skyapps.admobdemo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
```

proble is that when I run on real device that time AdMob banner is loaded but not display on device screen. All setting is done perfectly in Android Studio. Please help me....thanks in advance

Log cat...................

```
06-22 21:46:06.572  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? doing handshake -- ret=1
06-22 21:46:06.572  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? ssl=0x617efaf8 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
06-22 21:46:06.578  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=124 when=0 obj=Issued to: CN=*.g.doubleclick.net,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US;
Issued by: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US;
target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:06.578  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webview? setCertificate=Issued to: CN=*.g.doubleclick.net,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US;
Issued by: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US;
06-22 21:46:06.580  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=107 when=0 obj=GOOGLE LINK/sdk-core-v40.html target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:06.593  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/AppCacheHost? setCandidateApplicationCacheGroup(0x617c5188), set m_candidateApplicationCacheGroup as 0x62b137c0
06-22 21:46:06.597  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=108 when=0 obj=GOOGLE LILNK/sdk-core-v40.appcache target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? ssl=0x617efaf8 sslWrite buf=0x4189d6e8 len=595 write_timeout_millis=0
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? Doing SSL_write() with 595 bytes to go ssl=0x617efaf8, appData=0x614fdfd0
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? Returned from SSL_write() with result 595, error code 0 ssl=0x617efaf8, appData=0x614fdfd0
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? ssl=0x617efaf8 sslRead buf=0x41943448 len=1,timeo=60000
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x617efaf8, appData=0x614fdfd0
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? Returned from SSL_Read() with result -1, error code 2 ssl=0x617efaf8, appData=0x614fdfd0
06-22 21:46:06.613  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? sslSelect type=READ fd=111 appData=0x614fdfd0 timeout_millis=60000
06-22 21:46:06.637  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=108 when=0 obj=GOOGLE LINK/sdk-core-v40.js target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:06.703  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? sslSelect READ fd=111 appData=0x614fdfd0 timeout_millis=60000 => 1
06-22 21:46:06.703  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x617efaf8, appData=0x614fdfd0
06-22 21:46:06.747  24166-24479/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x617efaf8, appData=0x614fdfd0
06-22 21:46:06.775  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=106 when=0 target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:07.052  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=106 when=0 target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:07.226  24166-24538/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=26: interp stack at 0x5db51000
06-22 21:46:07.242  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webview? SELECTION_STRING_CHANGED
06-22 21:46:07.242  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? didFirstLayout standardLoad =true
06-22 21:46:07.242  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? Can't get the viewWidth yet
06-22 21:46:07.242  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webview? SAVE_WEBARCHIVE_FINISHED
06-22 21:46:07.242  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=125 when=0 target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? create interp thread : stack size=128KB
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? create new thread
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? new thread created
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? update thread list
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24539/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=27: interp stack at 0x5db71000
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24539/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=27: created from interp
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? start new thread
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24539/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=27: notify debugger
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24539/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=27 (Timer-1): calling run()
06-22 21:46:07.243  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=106 when=-1ms target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:07.244  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=125 when=-1ms target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {41a59460} }
06-22 21:46:07.353  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@419ed0f0
06-22 21:46:07.353  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242413874,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
 06-22 21:46:07.389  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@41a3e7f8
06-22 21:46:07.389  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242415213,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
06-22 21:46:07.959  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/CallbackProxy? CallbackProxy#handleMessage, msg = { what=108 when=0 obj=https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=3&s=gmob&action=&e=318474146,&rt=crf.1298,cr_bl.1681,cr_il.1982,cri.1991 target=Handler (android.webkit.CallbackProxy) {419e3800} }
06-22 21:46:07.960  24166-24413/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/chromium/tcp? LogConnectStart:ssl/csi.gstatic.com:443
`enter code here`06-22 21:46:07.960  24166-24413/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/chromium/tcp? LogConnectStart:ssl/csi.gstatic.com:443
06-22 21:46:07.960  24166-24413/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/chromium/tcp? LogConnectEnd:ssl/csi.gstatic.com:443:-1
06-22 21:46:07.960  24166-24413/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/chromium/tcp? LogConnectEnd:ssl/csi.gstatic.com:443:-1
06-22 21:46:08.006  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/libc-netbsd? getaddrinfo: csi.gstatic.com get result from proxy >>
06-22 21:46:08.199  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@41a23298
06-22 21:46:08.199  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242416053,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
06-22 21:46:08.211  24166-24413/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/chromium/tcp? LogConnectStart:ssl/csi.gstatic.com:443
06-22 21:46:08.211  24166-24413/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/chromium/tcp? LogConnectEnd:ssl/csi.gstatic.com:443:-1
06-22 21:46:08.290  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/GraphicBuffer? create handle(0x614ddd88) (w:480, h:854, f:1)
06-22 21:46:08.299  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo I/SurfaceTextureClient? [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f7a5008) fps:0.16, dur:6135.16, max:6135.16, min:6135.16
06-22 21:46:08.299  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo I/SurfaceTextureClient? [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5f7a5008, api:1, last queue time elapsed:6135.16
06-22 21:46:08.301  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/GraphicBuffer? create handle(0x5db97fe0) (w:208, h:77, f:1)
06-22 21:46:08.304  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo I/SurfaceTextureClient? [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x617ebd88) fps:0.46, dur:2183.13, max:2183.13, min:2183.13
06-22 21:46:08.306  24166-24180/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/IPCThreadState? [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x605c0f88
06-22 21:46:08.321  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo W/Choreographer? Frame time is 0.060597 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
06-22 21:46:08.328  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@419f0bb8
06-22 21:46:08.329  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242416184,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
06-22 21:46:08.367  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo I/InputMethodManager? handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE true, was false
06-22 21:46:08.652  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@41954ce8
06-22 21:46:08.652  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242416507,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
06-22 21:46:08.916  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=28: interp stack at 0x5ddf5000
06-22 21:46:08.931  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? NativeCrypto_EVP_VerifyInit ctx=0x5da7e390
06-22 21:46:08.931  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? NativeCrypto_EVP_VerifyInit algorithmChars=RSA-SHA1
06-22 21:46:08.933  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? NativeCrypto_EVP_VerifyInit ctx=0x5da7e3a8
06-22 21:46:08.933  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/NativeCrypto? NativeCrypto_EVP_VerifyInit algorithmChars=RSA-SHA1
06-22 21:46:08.951  24166-24418/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/dalvikvm? threadid=28: bye!
06-22 21:46:09.536  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/GraphicBuffer? close handle(0x617ec9d0) (w:208 h:77 f:1)
06-22 21:46:09.537  24166-24166/com.skyapps.admobdemo D/GraphicBuffer? close handle(0x5db97fe0) (w:208 h:77 f:1)
06-22 21:46:10.707  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@41993630
06-22 21:46:10.707  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242418562,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
06-22 21:46:12.764  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? LOAD_URL arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebViewCore$GetUrlData@418d3290
06-22 21:46:12.764  24166-24351/com.skyapps.admobdemo V/webcore? CORE loadUrl javascript:AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"viewBox":{"bottom":569,"right":320,"left":0,"top":0},"isPaused":false,"adFormat":"320x50_as","localVisibleBoxVisible":false,"activeViewJSON":{"activeview_cid":"5GgFaqS1wQWutFHYIIRZGqzt6hc","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"click_string":"CnzbAwzSIVc_aHoekoAPBv4O4Bf2x48oExen39KgB5Kvp5bgBEAEgAGDlgoCAqA6CAR5jYS1oYS1hcHAtcHViLTM5NDAyNTYwOTk5NDI1NDSIAQGgAfvU0tcDqQJzSdfAXQyqPqgDAaoEiwFP0JBQebjyO2_ENyjcepu-I8XwJokH7qBPK1v-di0gOEfQctCuwnA_4cVeCSyMWprk45qBA_cjDStFCS-XEFaUyerHETKTmeRVTW6VG2v2UPAlR2sKkOt7w3gK6TOeq10rGvJcAYOnfAdrGogP08WiOKCNyeMDptwDy1l7SdBKZgJ-kNVQBzB4dt9NkAYBoAYCwAYLgAftqq0omAcBqAemvhvYBwE","active_experiment_ids":""},"hashCode":"7ef4b35e-2e5b-4b61-a62c-241dd5e98d48","afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v7574000.7571000.1","windowVisibility":0,"screenDensity":1.5,"localVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isAttachedToWindow":true,"timestamp":4242420617,"globalVisibleBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isVisible":false,"adBox":{"bottom":300,"right":16,"left":16,"top":300},"hitBox":{"bottom":0,"right":0,"left":0,"top":0},"isMraid":false,"globalVisibleBoxVisible":false,"isStopped":false}]});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes post your logcat stacktrace.

Comment: There is no any error getting it's run perfectly and also display Toast message on onLoaded() method but banner is not display @Raj Sharma

Comment: I have added logcat @William

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that. Can you add all the logcat as code

Comment: added logcat again @William

Comment: @SubhashKhimani have another go. You need to get all of your logcat within the code element boundaries. Look at how your question is formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have padding left or right in your layout remove it and try again! I had the same problem with you and I just solve it with that trick